# How can we schedule a job to run in Oracle ( sql developer or Toad ) , to trigger a mail whoever are recently connected to particular database

Tags: oracle, jobs

Is there a way how can i get all the users recently connected to particular database along with their Host Name .  I want to trigger this Sql or procedure in a form of job and schedule the job in oracle to run in every one hour.

Please suggest with any options.

Comment: You can create a database-level after logon trigger - http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0560__Trigger/Databaselogontrigger.htm

Comment: @OldProgrammer .. Thanks a lot for the reply. How can i schedule this in a job in oracle ?

Comment: @Ravi Does your audit trail capture logon information?  If so, you can use `DBMS_SCHEDULER` to create an hourly job that reads from `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL`, creates a report, and emails the report with `UTL_MAIL`.  I've built jobs like that several times.

Comment: @JonHeller .. Yes we have DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL .. Do we need right a trigger ?  If you have syntax and steps to create job using UTL_MAIL can you help me to share.

Comment: @JonHeller . Please help me how to create jobs in DBMS scheduler. I need to do this for the first time..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is not a coding service. First write a procedure which query `V$SESSION` or `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL` and put result to mail. If you get problem with that, ask SO for help. Then create the `SCHEDULER JOB`, Again, if you get problem with that, ask SO for help.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit ..Thanks for the reply.  I am not asking for coding service and i am not expecting that as well. I am just asking if there is any oracle web link where i can find out steps to create a job then i want to do it myself. I tried to search but i am unable to get the exact link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below PL/SQL block creates a job that looks at the audit trail, creates a list of users and hosts that have logged on in the past hour, and emails the results.

Before the code can work, you may have to install `UTL_MAIL`:

```
sqlplus sys/<pwd>
SQL> @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlmail.sql
SQL> @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/prvtmail.plb
```

You may also need to set the parameter `SMTP_OUT_SERVER`, and possibly configure an ACL in the database to give you permission to send emails.  Just follow the error messages and use Google to fix them.

If your database is not already auditing connections, run:

```
audit connect;
```

Finally, create the job like below.  This is a very simple, text formatted email using `DBMS_SCHEDULER`, `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL`, and `UTL_MAIL`.

```
--Create an hourly job to email the last hours worth of logons.
begin
    dbms_scheduler.create_job(
        job_name        => 'hourly_logons',
        job_type        => 'plsql_block',
        start_date      => systimestamp at time zone 'US/Eastern',
        repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly;byminute=0;',
        enabled         => true,
        job_action      =>
        q'[
            declare
                v_message varchar2(32767);
            begin
                --Create the message based on audit entries.
                for rows in
                (
                    select username, userhost, count(*) the_count
                    from dba_audit_trail
                    where timestamp > systimestamp - interval '1' hour
                        and action_name = 'LOGON'
                    group by username, userhost
                    order by 1,2
                ) loop
                    v_message := v_message || rows.username || chr(9) || rows.userhost || chr(9) ||
                        rows.the_count || chr(10);
                end loop;

                --Email the message
                utl_mail.send
                (
                    sender     => 'some_address@some_domain.com',
                    recipients => 'some_address@some_domain.com',
                    subject    => 'Logons in past hour',
                    message    => v_message
                );
            end;
        ]'
    );
end;
/
```

You may want to manually run the job during testing, and check the scheduler metadata:

```
--Force the job to run:
begin
    dbms_scheduler.run_job('HOURLY_LOGONS');
end;
/

--Check the job status and history.
select * from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'HOURLY_LOGONS';
select * from dba_scheduler_job_run_details where job_name = 'HOURLY_LOGONS' order by log_date desc;
```

The above code is not tested because I don't have a mail server setup on my home machine.  But I've done this several times before and am certain that something very close to this should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon . I will test this one. Can you suggest me ,if we can capture these results into an excel in run time itself. Is there any way i can capture.

Comment: @Ravi Yes you can certainly turn the results into an Excel spreadsheet.  There are several open source options, but I personally prefer to use [ORA_EXCEL](https://www.oraexcel.com/).  In my experience, the open source programs only work well for a small number of rows.  If you need to send thousands of rows it's worth paying a few bucks for a commercial program.  Once you have created a BLOB for the file with ORA_EXCEL, you can email the attachment with [SEND_MAIL](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql#attachment).